# ImageBrush control cannot be identified using Coded UI cross hair or Inspect.exe

Tags: automation, windows-store-apps, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am automating a windows 8.1 store app using Coded UI test. I have a    Imagebrush control where user image will be loaded on service call. The thing is I cannot identify this control using Coded UI Cross hair/Inspect.exe eventhough it have automation id supplied. But the Image control can be identified.

The below XAML have two border elements and within the 1st border element I am having Imagebrush control and in the next border element I am having image control. Here I can identify the Image control but the Imagebrush control cannot be identified. I tried hand coding also but it did not work.

```
<Border AutomationProperties.AutomationId="123" Tapped="MyProfile_Tapped">
  <Border.Background>
   <ImageBrush AutomationProperties.AutomationId="123_4" ImageSource="{Binding Profile.ProfilePhot....... />
  </Border.Background>
</Border>

<Border AutomationProperties.AutomationId="1234_5">
  <Image AutomationProperties.AutomationId="1234_6" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/WatchAlbumLogo.png" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Did you re-target for windows 8.1 [Coded UI Testing for your Windows 8.1 Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2013/10/24/from-the-mvps-getting-started-with-coded-ui-testing-for-your-windows-8-1-store-apps.aspx)

Comment: Yea it is already re-targeted to 8.1 from 8.0. The thing is if I keep button control or text block in that place it is identified. But in case of Imagebrush it is not identified.